# Sum substring values from an array of delimited strings

Tags: php, arrays, sum, substring, delimited

I have two cookies and their values like this:

```
foreach ($_COOKIE as $key => $val) {
    $piece = explode(",", $val);
    $t_cost = array($piece[3]);
    print_r($t_cost); //It prints Array ( [0] => 11 ) Array ( [0] => 11 )
    echo $total_cost = array_sum($t_cost);
}
```

But it prints only one value. How can I add the both values to sum them?

Comment: Push each value ($t_cost) in a new array then apply the array--sum on that array?

Comment: This question doesn't contain a clear [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need array_sum, just use += operator it will save a bit of memory

```
$t_cost = 0;
foreach($_COOKIE as $key=>$val) {
    $piece = explode(",", $val);
    $t_cost += $piece[3];
}
echo $t_cost;
```

Comment: How does that work because it works can you explain me?

Comment: `$key` doesn't appear to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of `array_sum` actually.

```
// the array where all piece[3] values are stored
$t_cost = array();

// loop through array
// just foreach($_COOKIE as $val) is enough
foreach($_COOKIE as $key=>$val) {

    // split by comma
    $piece = explode(",", $val);

    // add to array
    $t_cost[] = $piece[3];

}
// sum up  
$total_cost = array_sum($t_cost);
```

or just

```
$total = 0;
foreach($_COOKIE as $key=>$val) {
        $piece = explode(",", $val);  
        $total += $piece[3];
}
echo $total;
```

Comment: `$key` doesn't appear to be useful.

Comment: @mickmackusa: You're right in current context its not needed,  as you can see OP posted problem with  foreach ..., I just showed one of possible methods to get required output.

Answer (score 1):

```
$total = 0;
foreach($_COOKIE as $key=>$val) {
      $piece = explode(",", $val);
      $t_cost = trim(str_replace('$', '', array($piece[3]));
      $total += (float)$t_cost;
      echo "The total cost: $".$total;
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.